# Eating Rice without a Sukkah

Tags: halacha, food, sukkah

There's a general rule that non-Mezonos (or Hamotzi) items can be eaten outside a Sukkah (not *should*, but *can*). Does the same apply to rice, which is only "somewhat" Mezonos (Borei Nefashos is said after eating it), or does rice also fall into the same category as bread and cookies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch O.C. 639:2) requires a sukkah absolutely only by  a significant amount of bread, and the 5 grains when you are subjectively kovea seuda (the Magen Avraham doesn't require kvias seuda).  The halachic relation of rice to the other 5 grains is that rice satiates enough to get a mezonos, but is not similar in its use as a seuda.  It would not require sukkah absolutely.

[However, the acharonim strongly suggest eating any significant kvias seuda in a sukkah (M.B. 639:15)]

Answer (score 11):

Rav Ovadia Yossef Shlita allows to eat rice outside a Sukkah (Halichot Olam, Helek Beth, p281).

Moadim Besimh'a.

Comment: Do you know where that's written?  (Yalkut Yosef, Yechaveh Da'at, ?)

Comment: I read it in Halichot Olam. 
Bli neder, I'll try to find the exact reference tonight.

Comment: In halichot Olam, helek Beth, p281.
In Yalqout Yossef, kitsur CA, siman 639:13